# chrome.tabs.create not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

Because my content script cannot use all the chrome API tools, I am sending a message from my content script to my background script. When received, the background script is supposed to open a new tab containing an html file I had made.

This is sending the message from the content script...

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({permission: true}, function(response) {
        console.log(response.access);
});
```

This is the code to receive the message in my background script...

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.permission == true) {
        chrome.tabs.create({'url': chrome.extension.getURL('./src/permission.html')}, function(tab) {
            sendResponse({access: "yes"});
        });  
    }
});
```

The message is received, I have already tested that. But when I add the following code...

```
chrome.tabs.create({'url': chrome.extension.getURL('./src/permission.html')}, function(tab) {
...etc
```

I get an error saying response not received. Meaning something must have broke inside my `chrome.tabs.create`. Why is it breaking?

The `permission.html` path is relative to the background script.

What I want is for a new tab to be created when the message is received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this has any affect, but the content scripts and the background scripts communicate asyncronously so for you to use the `sendResponse` callback, you'll need to `return true;` at the end of your onMessage anonymous function.

[Chrome onMessage return true](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage)

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.permission == true) {
        chrome.tabs.create({'url': chrome.extension.getURL('./src/permission.html')}, function(tab) {
            sendResponse({access: "yes"});
        });  
    }
    return true; //to tell the content script to look out for sendResponse
});
```

**Again, I'm not sure if this will solve your problem, but regardless, your response using sendResponse will not work without returning true at the end of the listener**

Also, BTW, `chome.extension.getURL()` does not need a dot-slash so `chrome.extension.getURL('src/permission.html')` should be enough.

Have you tried just running

```
chrome.tabs.create({'url': chrome.extension.getURL('src/permission.html')});
```

(with or without the dot-slash) to see if the tab opens up?

Comment: unfortunately none of those solutions helped. The tab still will not open

Comment: Can you try just running the command? Go to chrome://extensions and then (making sure "Developer mode" is checked) click "background page" of your extension. Once the Developer Tool opens up, go to the console tab and just try to open directly by executing `chrome.tabs.create({'url': chrome.extension.getURL('src/permission.html')});`